# C Programming: strtok delivers segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, token

I am trying to tokenize a string by spaces and tabs. However, when I run my program, I get the a Segmentation Fault error when I try to print the token. I don't understand why this is happening, as the print statement doesn't work whether I use `token` or I deference token with `*token`. Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string = "String1 String2 String3";
    char *token = strtok(string," \t"); /* The atomic weights and names are separated by either a space or tab */

    while (token != NULL) /* While there is still content for us to read */
    {
        printf("token = %s\n", *token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " \t"); 
    }

    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: `char string = ` should be `char string[] = `

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings - there are some very obvious problems which the compiler will point out if you let it.

Comment: You declared `string` as `char` rather than `char[]`. For slightly arcane reasons this isn't an error, but it should at least warn.

Comment: Always check your compiler's warnings! With `gcc`, I use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: Also, why did you decide to dereference `token` when printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `char string` needs to be either `char *string` or `char string[]` instead. You are trying to assign a whole string to a single `char`.

Second, string literals are read-only data, but `strtok()` modifies the `char` buffer it is given. So your code has **undefined behavior** since it is trying to modify read-only memory.

If you change `char string` to `char string[]`, the string literal data will be copied into a writable buffer at runtime. And then change `*token` to `token` when calling `printf()`, since `%s` is expecting a `char*` pointer, not a single `char`. Then your code will work as expected:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "String1 String2 String3";
    char *token = strtok(string," \t"); /* The atomic weights and names are separated by either a space or tab */

    while (token != NULL) /* While there is still content for us to read */
    {
        printf("token = %s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
    }

    //exit(1);
    return 1;
}
```